# Как использовать плагин для js hotkeys?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-10, button, hotkeys

Необходимо забиндить горячую клавишу на нажатие определенного элемента сайта. Наткнулся на плагин js-hotkeys, но не могу понять, как его использовать (не работал с веб кодингом, поэтому и задаю такие глупые вопросы). Браузер Хром. Если есть другая простая реализация горячих клавиш, не могли бы показать ее
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека весьма простая, вся нужная информация и примеры есть в [документации](https://wangchujiang.com/hotkeys/).

В `head` мы подключаем эту самую библиотеку. В`body` добавим кнопку для примера и подключим наш скрипт:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/hotkeys-js/dist/hotkeys.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="test-btn">Click me</button>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Далее в `script.js` пишем код:

```js
// Получим кнопки по id
const button = document.querySelector('#test-btn'); 

// Повесим на кнопку событие при клике
const onButtonClick = () => alert('Button is pressed');
button.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick); 

// Зарегистрируем новое сочетание клавиш alt+h
hotkeys('alt+h', (event, handler) => {
  // Тут два варианта использования
  // Предпочтительный. Вызов той же функции, что и на кнопке
  onButtonClick();
  
  // Либо эмулирование нажатия на элемент
  button.click();
});
```

Стоит заметить, что если клавиша или сочетание клавиш уже занято браузером - стандартное поведение нужно отменить с помощью `event.preventDefault()`:

```js
// f5 - перезагрузка страницы
hotkeys('f5', (event, handler) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   //...
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! А для этих элементов как реализовать клик?
 <span class="controls-BaseButton__text controls-text-label controls-Button__text-label_viewMode-link controls-Button__text_viewMode-link" tabindex="0">Задействовать</span> 

| <span class="controls-BaseButton__text controls-Button__text_clickable_bg-same controls-Button__text_viewMode-outlined" tabindex="0">Отозвать</span>

Comment: Аналогично, с помощью `querySelector`. В аргументы передаются аналогичные CSS селекторы. Внутрь придется передать длинную строку: `const elem = document.querySelector('.controls-BaseButton__text.controls-text-label...'); elem.click();`. Но если вы можете добавить уникальные классы или айди к этим элементам - лучше так и сделать, тогда обращаться будет проще. Подробнее [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: Если мой ответ был вам полезен, можете его отметить. Это будет самое лучшее спасибо :)

Comment: вот бы еще кто код написал для этого элемента <span class="controls-BaseButton__text controls-text-label controls-Button__text-label_viewMode-link controls-Button__text_viewMode-link" tabindex="0">Задействовать</span> хд

Comment: Добавьте в ваш элемент `id="tab-0"` или что-то типа того, и сможете обратиться через `const elem = document.querySelector('#tab-0')`;

Comment: то есть можно вписать любой id? я что-то запутался, как должен выглядеть полный код клика на элемент событием клавиша нажата

Comment: Да, id можно взять какой удобнее. Вам бы больше сделать упор на базовые знания html/css/js

Comment: Да мне просто изучать некогда, а скрипт нужен именно сейчас, а то делаю одни и те же нажатия 1000 раз, когда можно автоматизировать